# html issue when placing content in the body

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to add some content to a website and when I place the new content the other contents are moved down when I alter the margins of the new content. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a sample code of the html

```
<ul class="listing">
<li><a href="R">R</a></li>
<li><a href="I">I</a></li>
<li><a href="V">V</a></li>
</ul>

<p class ="something">
<a href="R.jpg"><img src="r.jpg"/></a>

</p>
```

and the css that goes with it

```
.listing li{display: inline}
ul.listing{margin-left: 200px;
       background: gray;
       box-shadow: 0 0 20px #457;
       width: 600px;
       margin-top: 200px;
       }
p.something{background: white;
   margin: auto;
   margin-top: 100px;
   margin-left: 200px;
   padding: 10px;
   width: 920px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 20px #457}
```

Comment: What do you actually want it to look like?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what content is moving where when changing which margins?

Comment: It doesnt matter what I add. It moves down whatever content I add. Thinking about it makes sense. All i have to do is keep moving the content around to fit the layout of the site. But it is kind of a hassle, so I was trying to figure out a way to keep stuff in locked positions.

Comment: Nope. Still don't have a single clue of what your problem is or what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your sentence word by word: "so I was trying to figure out a way to keep stuff in locked positions"

```
p.something{
position: fixed;
}
```

OR

```
p.something{
position: absolute;
}
```

should help you, depending what exactly you want to have. (p.somehting ist the staff you want to have fixed somewhere on your page/browser window)

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper, remove the single margin-left from all elements, apply them to the wrapper, that way you only need to set it once

http://jsbin.com/ejepoc/1/

See this example.